# Implementation of dependency injection using C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to patterns and am trying to understand the concept of using interfaces to prevent tight coupling. I have created a class:

```
public interface Imul
{
    int multi(int a, int b);
}
```

I implemented this interface in a separate `mul` class:

```
public class mul: Imul
{
   public int multi(int a, int b) => return a * b;
}
```

Now here is my problem: in the main program how should I write it to understand the concept of in-dependency?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     // Implementation
}
```

Comment: You should ask some specific problem or difficulty. In your case, you are asking for a whole explanation almost from scratch, and Stack Overflow is not a place for that. If I were you, I'd look for a good article on the web, or a Youtube video.

Comment: @Andrew difficulty is how should i implement it in my Main class

Comment: Short answer: using an Inversion of Control container. Long answer: look for an article, or check that "This question already has an answer here" text above.

Comment: @Andrew i have read many,i understood the concept,but i do not know how to implement it,how should i use IMUL in the main program,to pass parameters to my class,without instantiating the class

Comment: Then you didn't understand it yet... The idea behind DI is to avoid tightly coupling classes. So for example, if you have a `ProcessData` class, instead of it doing `new mul().multi(x, y)`, its constructor will be like `ProcessData(Imul imul)`, it will store that parameter locally (let's say in `_imul`) and then it will call `_imul.multi(x, y)`.  So `ProcessData` never creates `mul`, it simply receives it in the constructor. When instead of multiplying you need to sum values, you will just create `ProcessData` giving it as a parameter a different class that implements `Imul`.

Comment: By the way, that interface name is probably not a good one, a better name could be `IOperation` and the method could be `Do`, so `ProcessData` would call `_ioperation.Do(x, y)`, which clearly shows it could be any type of binary operation. With an interface called `Imul`, you are saying that the class will do... only a multiplication, leaving no room for different implementations.